# How to add an UITextView in a resizable UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I need a text view inside of a resizable cell - the cell is resizing in real time, based on a specific timer/stopwatch. I can't simply put the text view inside the cell, because I'm resizing rows with `reloadRowsAtIndexPath:` every 10ms and that's causing the `UITextView` to resign first responder. I am trying to avoid calling `becomeFirstResponder` every time so what I did now was that I created an external text view and added it on top of the table view, so it basically only acts as if it was inside the cell.

Do you have any suggestions how else I could do this in a less hackish way?

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't reload the table (contents) to resize. Just use:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

This will resize the cells but not reload the cells itself, so it should not resign the first repsonder.

Comment: So that will basically invoke heightForRow.. but not cellForRow..?

Comment: Yes, this is because you are not updating any cells between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, but `endUpdates` forces the tableView to reload the cell heights.

Comment: Tried and tt's not reloading cell heights fast enough. Looks like it's too slow - it only updates properly when I enter text (the cell gets redrawn I guess?).

Comment: I don't think it's these methods that are slow, it's the most efficient way to resize your cells. But I just noticed you are doing this every 10ms? That's 100 times each second(!) (why so much?), this will very likely consume all the resources, making things very slow. Try starting with a much bigger interval.

Comment: I want it to smoothly resize as the audio plays along, so I've set it so it updates with the audio playback. Do you have any other ideas how I can achieve smooth resizing and tableview functionality? Thanks.

Comment: The resizing is usually done animated, so should be smooth. You probably just need to optimize your code, so it will only resize cells when really necessary. So.. When do you really need to resize the cells, probably only when the textbox size changes? In that case you should just trigger a resize then, but reloading/resizing a tableview 100 times per second is the real issue here (not the resizing itself or smoothness).

Comment: No, I'd like to resize the row in sync with the playback. So it doesnt resize once, but simultaneously as the audio is played back. When you stop playback, the resizing should also stop, and when you continue, the resizing (growing) should continue.

Answer (score 1):

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
Call these methods if you want to perform operations simultaneously.
beginUpdates and endUpdates should be nested properly within the codes. These are the efficient methods that has been provided to us.